# Reordering layers in ArcMap using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, layers, draw-order

I am trying to automate a map I create every so often. The map flags counties based on certain commodities, and color codes them based on price changes. I am able to get each layer created, but would like to reorder the commodities so the "red" commodities are on top, orange below that, low risk below that, and then move the State layer to the top.

My code is below - the error result I get is:

```
Assertion Error: Did not find move layer
```

```
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]    

arcpy.AddJoin_management("County_Projected_AEAC", "ID", "C:/Users/SS/Desktop/ArcGIS Maps/MTW/Spring_2020.xlsx/Spring_2020_MTW$", "modified_FIPS", "KEEP_ALL")    
arcpy.Select_analysis("County_Projected_AEAC", "C:/Users/SS/Desktop/ArcGIS Maps/MTW/Beef_Cattle_Python.shp", '"Spring_2020_MTW$.Flag_Beef_Cattle" = 1')
arcpy.Select_analysis("County_Projected_AEAC", "C:/Users/SS/Desktop/ArcGIS Maps/MTW/Feed_Cattle_Python.shp", '"Spring_2020_MTW$.Flag_Feed_Cattle" = 1')
arcpy.Select_analysis("County_Projected_AEAC", "C:/Users/SS/Desktop/ArcGIS Maps/MTW/Corn_Python.shp", '"Spring_2020_MTW$.Flag_Corn" = 1')
arcpy.Select_analysis("County_Projected_AEAC", "C:/Users/SS/Desktop/ArcGIS Maps/MTW/Cotton_Python.shp", '"Spring_2020_MTW$.Flag_Cotton" = 1')
arcpy.Select_analysis("County_Projected_AEAC", "C:/Users/SS/Desktop/ArcGIS Maps/MTW/Dairy_Python.shp", '"Spring_2020_MTW$.Flag_Dairy" = 1')
arcpy.Select_analysis("County_Projected_AEAC", "C:/Users/SS/Desktop/ArcGIS Maps/MTW/Hogs_Python.shp", '"Spring_2020_MTW$.Flag_Hogs" = 1')
arcpy.Select_analysis("County_Projected_AEAC", "C:/Users/SS/Desktop/ArcGIS Maps/MTW/Poultry_Python.shp", '"Spring_2020_MTW$.Flag_Poultry" = 1')
arcpy.Select_analysis("County_Projected_AEAC", "C:/Users/SS/Desktop/ArcGIS Maps/MTW/Soybeans_Python.shp", '"Spring_2020_MTW$.Flag_Soybeans" = 1')
arcpy.Select_analysis("County_Projected_AEAC", "C:/Users/SS/Desktop/ArcGIS Maps/MTW/Wheat_Python.shp", '"Spring_2020_MTW$.Flag_Wheat" = 1')

States = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[-1]
County = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[-2]
Beef_Cattle = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[-3]
Feed_Cattle = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[-4]
Corn = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[-5]
Cotton = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[-6]
Dairy = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[-7]
Hogs = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[-8]
Poultry = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[-9]
Soybeans = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[-10]
Wheat = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[-11]

low_risk_commodities = [Poultry]
for x in low_risk_commodities:
    x.visible = False
    arcpy.RefreshTOC()

orange_commodities = [Wheat, Hogs, Dairy, Cotton, Corn, Feed_Cattle, Beef_Cattle]

for x in orange_commodities:
    arcpy.mapping.MoveLayer(df, arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0], x)
```

The code is correctly turning off the poultry layer but will not move the layers due to the error. I know it is likely in how I'm defining the layers, but I'm not sure how to properly do this.

When I type in Wheat, it gives me a little purplish icon, indicating it is maybe not a layer but is maybe a shapefile?

Comment: I think you should reduce your code snippet to getting it working with 3 layers. Also, pleases remove the ellipses at the beginning of many of your lines of code. Potential answerers are far more likely to test code that they can simply copy/paste.

Comment: Did you exclude `Soybeans` intentionally from `orange_commodities` list?

Comment: How many layers are there in TOC? It would be helpful if you added TOC structure after running `Select_analysis` lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, `Wheat` layer is the first layer. You get that error, because reference layer (`arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0]`) and move layer (`x`) are the same (`Wheat`) at first running of `MoveLayer` method.

Change `for` loop in following way:

```
for x in orange_commodities:
    ref_layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0]
    if ref_layer != x:
        arcpy.mapping.MoveLayer(df, arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0], x)
```

Comment: I'll try shifting the order and let you know. If I still have issues, I'll post the TOC structure after the select analysis lines like you mentioned.

Comment: The TOC Structure is as follows:
Wheat_Python
Soybeans_Python
Poultry_Python
Hogs_Python
Dairy_Python
Cotton_Python
Corn_Python
Feed_Cattle_Python
Beef_Cattle_Python
County_Projected_AEAC
States_Projected

Answer (score 0):

For AcrGIS Pro, you can reorder layers relative to eachother:

```
layer_one = map.listLayers("name1")[0] 
layer_two = map.listLayers("name2")[0] 
map.moveLayer(layer_one, layer_two)
```

--An optional third parameter sets AFTER or BEFORE (The default value is BEFORE)

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/map-class.htm